# Git access rights

Tags: server, git

I'm trying to add second user for remote shared repository

Added group git dev, second user added to this group

repository initialized with:

```
git init --bare --shared=group   
sudo chgrp -R developers .
```

But second user cannot clone:

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Which permissions should be added?

It also will be useful describe how to setup shared repository for few users on ubuntu from scratch

Comment: I recommend using [Gitosis](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis). It is easy to setup and you can configure user groups, and read/write permissions for these groups on each repository. Users are authorized by ssh public keys - they do not even need to be registered as system users.

Comment: did you log out and log back in after change group memberships?

Answer (score 1):

Your developers will need at least read files (g+r) and read and execute directories (g+rx) permissions to pull and write (g+w) permissions to push.

Easy way of setting it all up:

```
chgrp -R developers .
find . -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} \;
```

Some ideas:

1. When you add new users to some group, the users need to logout and login again for the new group permissions to be applicable.
2. check that your bare repository has sufficient group permissions (sometimes your umask may be too restrictive and omit write-rights for the group etc).
3. Check that not just the repository has enough permissions, but also the parent directories are at least executable for your developers.

Comment: drwxrwsr-x 6 user developers 4096 Oct 19 17:23 project.git
still no changes

Comment: @ziftech what about parent directories?

Comment: repository resides in /home/user1 directory, shoud I set permissions to it?

Comment: yes, all the parents should be executable, see idea #3